# How can I add a comment that refers to more than one highlighted text in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

How can I add a comment that refers to more than one highlighted text in Adobe Acrobat Pro XI?

For example, I would like this comment to be linked to the two highlighted strings, so that I don't have to copy-paste the same comment for both highlighted strings:

[image]

I use Adobe Acrobat Pro XI with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly, because the highlight *is the comment*.

What you could do as a workaround, is for example, add a sticky note comment, or use color coding with your comments.